# Checking for windows line breaks in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to loop over an input file that takes an unlimited amount of parameters

```
let whiteSpaceAndNL = NSMutableCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()

while let command = scanner.scanUpToCharactersFromSet(whiteSpaceAndNL) {
  switch command {
    case "reset":
      print("Resetting")
    case "run":
      let label = scanner.scanUpToCharactersFromSet(whiteSpaceAndNL)
      print("Running: \(label)")

      // This doesn't work
      let lastChar = scanner.string[scanner.string.startIndex.advancedBy(scanner.scanLocation)]
      let newlineChars = NSMutableCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
      while !scanner.atEnd && newlineChars.characterIsMember(lastChar) {
        let nextParam = scanner.scanUpToCharactersFromSet(whiteSpaceAndNL)
        print(nextParam)
      }

    default: break
  }
}
```

In most cases I only need to know the first item on a line, because the rest of the line will follow a specific format with a specific number of items.
However, in the "run" case any number of parameters can be inserted after the label. 
Therefore I need to distinguish between whitespace and newlines, if the scanner scans until whitespace there will be another parameter, otherwise there will be a new command.

I had 'solved' this by checking if the last character (lastChar) before the current scanLocation was a newline character ("\n"). This worked on my machine but I ran into problems with input from some machines, most likely due to windows line endings.

```
while !scanner.atEnd && scanner.string[scanner.string.startIndex.advancedBy(scanner.scanLocation)] != "\n" {
```

Can anyone explain to me while the second code snippet doesn't work on some machines? The first code snippet is my attempt at improving the code, but this does not work because lastChar is not a unicode character.

Comment: You need to also test for `\r` and for `\r\n`. Extend the characterset if needed.

Comment: @Eric The problem still exists if I use
`while !scanner.atEnd && (scanner.string[scanner.string.startIndex.advancedBy(scanner.scanLocation)] != "\n" || scanner.string[scanner.string.startIndex.advancedBy(scanner.scanLocation)] != "\r\n" || scanner.string[scanner.string.startIndex.advancedBy(scanner.scanLocation)] != "\r") `

Comment: Then show us these problematic `windows line endings` you get, if they're different.

Comment: I should have used && instead of || in the previous statement, this way it only checks the "\n". It does use "\r\n" line endings as expected. The main problem is not solved yet, but I'm one step further. Thanks :)